# Connecting to WFS - no feature types available in parameters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, wfs, data-interoperability

I've installed the interoperability connection folder on arcgis 10.2 and I'm going through the steps to view a WFS. I've got to the WFS Parameters and I'm trying to select the Feature Types from the Constraints box but there are no feature types listed? Would this be because the URL is wrong? Any help please?